# Counting the number of times a value appears in an CSV FIle using C#

Tags: c#, linq, csv, datagridview

I have a CSV File that i want to filter something like this

Example of my CSV File:

```
Name,LastName,Date
David,tod,09/09/1990
David,lopez,09/09/1994
David,cortez,09/09/1994
Maurice,perez,09/09/1980
Maurice,ruiz,09/09/1996
```

I want to know, How many people were born between date 1 (01/01/1990) and date 2 (01/01/1999) (with datetimepicker)

And the datagridview should it show something like this:

```
Name,Frecuency
David,3
Maurice,1
```

I dont know how do it with compare dates,  but I have this code with linq logic

```
DataTable dtDataSource = new DataTable();

    dtDataSource.Columns.Add("Name");
    dtDataSource.Columns.Add("Frecuency");

    int[] array = new int[10];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 1;
    array[2] = 1;
    array[3] = 2;
    array[4] = 1;
    array[5] = 2;
    array[6] = 1;
    array[7] = 1;
    array[8] = 2;
    array[9] = 3;

    var group = from i in array
                group i by i into g
                select new
                {
                    g.Key,
                    Sum = g.Count()
                };

    foreach (var g in group)
    {

        dtDataSource.Rows.Add(g.Key,g.Sum);
    }







    if (dtDataSource != null)
    {


        dataGridViewReporte.DataSource = dtDataSource;

    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best, and easiest, way to work with dates in .NET is with the `DateTimeOffset` structure.  This type exposes several methods for parsing dates (which makes converting the date strings from your CSV file easy), and also enables simple comparisons between dates with the standard operators.

See the [DateTimeOffset documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx).

*Note: .NET also has a `DateTime` structure.  I would encourage you to use `DateTimeOffset` wherever possible, as it helps prevent time zone bugs from creeping in to your code.*

#### Simple Example

As a simple example, this code demonstrates how you can parse a string to a `DateTimeOffset` in .NET, and then compare it to another date.

```
// Static property to get the current time, in UTC.
DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

string dateString = "09/09/1990";
DateTimeOffset date;

// Use TryParse to defensively parse the date.
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(dateString, out date))
{
    // The date is valid; we can use a standard operator to compare it.
    if (date < now)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The parsed date is in the past.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The parsed date is in the future.");
    }
}
```

#### Using LINQ

The key element you were missing from your sample code was a `Where` clause in the LINQ expression.  Now that we've seen how to parse dates, it's simply a matter of comparing them to the start and end dates you care about.

`.Where(p => p.BirthDate >= startDate && p.BirthDate <= endDate)`

*Note: I've found that LINQ expressions are really nice to work with when they're strongly typed to some object.  I've included a simple `Person` class in this example, which hopefully clears up the code a lot.  This should be fine for most cases, but do keep in mind that LINQ-to-Objects, while incredibly productive, is not always the most efficient solution when you have a **lot** of data.*

The `Person` class:

```
class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

Example code:

```
// Representing the CSV file as an array of strings.
var csv = new []
{
    "Name,LastName,Date",
    "David,tod,09/09/1990",
    "David,lopez,09/09/1994",
    "David,cortez,09/09/1994",
    "Maurice,perez,09/09/1980",
    "Maurice,ruiz,09/09/1996"
};

// Parse each line of the CSV file into a Person object, skipping the first line.
// I'm using DateTimeOffset.Parse for simplicity, but production code should 
// use the .TryParse method to be defensive.
var people = csv
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(line =>
    {
        var parts = line.Split(',');
        return new Person
        {
            FirstName = parts[0],
            LastName = parts[1],
            BirthDate = DateTimeOffset.Parse(parts[2]),
        };
    });

// Create start and end dates we can use to compare.
var startDate = new DateTimeOffset(year: 1990, month: 01, day: 01, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, offset: TimeSpan.Zero);
var endDate = new DateTimeOffset(year: 1999, month: 01, day: 01, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, offset: TimeSpan.Zero);

// First, we filter the people by their birth dates.
// Then, we group by their first name and project the counts.
var groups = people
    .Where(p => p.BirthDate >= startDate && p.BirthDate <= endDate)
    .GroupBy(p => p.FirstName)
    .Select(firstNameGroup => new
    {
        Name = firstNameGroup.Key,
        Count = firstNameGroup.Count(),
    });

foreach (var group in groups)
{
    dtDataSource.Rows.Add(group.Name, group.Count);
}
```

#### LINQ Syntax

As a matter of personal preference, I typically use the LINQ extension methods (`.Where`, `.Select`, `.GroupBy`, etc.) instead of the query syntax.  Following the style from your example above, the same query could be written as:

```
var groups = from p in people
             where p.BirthDate >= startDate && p.BirthDate <= endDate
             group p by p.FirstName into g
             select new
             {
                 Name = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Count(),
             };
```

Comment: Excellent logic! thank you so much @Ryan  ... But I want to read the CSV from a directory, like.. string csvfile = \\Names.csv".. How can I do it?

Comment: The simplest way will be to use the [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) method.  This will read the CSV file into an array of strings.  The MSDN page has another useful example.

In the above example, you could replace the first line with:
`var csv = File.ReadAllLines("names.csv");`.